# Do people use misery and misery guts the same way?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I m wondering whether I can use misery and misery guts the same way, such as in this sentence :

You re such a...

Does this mean the same thing?

I understood that both means to be in a bad mood

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your question is..I've never heard anyone say that someone is a "misery guts." Have you, actually?

Comment: I ve read it online.. You didn't? .

Comment: @Robusto It's definitely a British expression, though it's more of a working class expression than Standard English. I don't know if it's used elsewhere but I have a feeling that I've heard it on Australian TV programmes.

Comment: @BoldBen In Ireland we say : *he's such such a misery guts*. We wouldn't normally say *he's such such a misery*

Comment: @k1eran Both are used in England, but _he's such a misery_ can be thought of as being a bit "posher" than _he's such a misery guts_.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, or at least they shouldn't. Then again, we can't rule out  individual idiosyncrasies.
 "Misery guts" is a mild insult, whereas "misery" on its own is merely a noun. However, if I take that noun and use it to say (usually in a condescending tone) "You're a right misery today", that would be virtually synonymous with "You're a right misery guts today".
So, my final answer would be that yes, some people may use them both the same way, but I would advise non-native speakers against attempting to do so, due to the risk of not quite getting it right.